# How to download thousands of excel files from website?

Tags: python, excel, automation, download, consolidation

this is the website in question.

- https://clientportal.jse.co.za/downloadable-files?RequestNode=/Safex/agriculture.stats

I want to download every year's excel files from 2009.

I don't want to manually click all of them, any help? Not a lot of experience with coding so keep it simple please. I know python is an option but I don't have any experience with python, VBA could work but I am not having any luck there.

For now all I want to do is download them all, but if there is also a way to consolidate the files that would be very helpful too. In full honesty I can't code at all, but it seems that is the only way to do this task and might take to long to learn a whole coding language and need these files downloaded as soon as possible.

If this is too complicated, please advise if I should bite the bullet and manually do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked on here for any posts mentioning web scraping? there are several with code that you could edit to suit your needs.

Comment: Hi mike, I have however I need code tailored for this specific website, as I dont have the skills to use someone else's template and adapt it to my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you already have an environment in which you can run the code (if not, please install anaconda and use jupyter notebook), this code does the trick:

First time you have to install the libraries (run this only once):

```
%pip install bs4
%pip install requests
```

Then you can run the code:

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin 


def download_excel_files(url, download_path):

    response = requests.get(url)
    

    if response.status_code == 200:

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        
        links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
        
        for link in links:
            file_url = link['href']
            if file_url.endswith('.xls') or file_url.endswith('.xlsx'): 
                full_file_url = urljoin(url, file_url)
                file_name = os.path.join(download_path, os.path.basename(file_url))
                with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
                    file_response = requests.get(full_file_url)
                    f.write(file_response.content)
                print(f"File '{file_name}' succesfully downloaded")
    else:
        print("Page error")
```

And then you loop on the years and call the function like so:

```
base_url = 'https://clientportal.jse.co.za/downloadable-files?RequestNode=/Safex/agriculture.stats/'


for year in range(2009, 2025):
    url = base_url + str(year)
    download_folder = str(year)
    os.makedirs(download_folder, exist_ok=True)
    download_excel_files(url, download_folder)
```

Since I am assuming that you're just using the code for this purpose, I'll avoid to explain every passage. If you need something more please ask.

Comment: Thanks Federico for the quick respone, i will download anaconda and try to follow your steps. Your response was so quick damnn. I thought coding was liberated by AI, but spent a few hours trying to do this with Gemini/ChatGPT but without coding knowledge beforehand their advise is pretty much useless.

Comment: Your task is quite common, and adapt the code to a specific website is usually not that difficult. ChatGPT could be useful if you're already skilled, but totally useless if you know nothing about code, as 99% of the time it ouptus something that is not working and needs to be debugged and rearranged. Anyway, I edited the post since you would not have the libraries installed

Comment: Hi man, the code is running on jupyter and is downloading files as we speak. So cool !

Comment: So the code will run for a while, it is almost through the first year. Are the files going to appear in my downloaded folder?

Comment: in the last part of the code I'm creating a folder named as the year, so the files will appear in the specific year folder. Anyway, you should be able to see the files as the are downloaded, so if you're not still seeing anything (even if the code is still running) there might be something wrong

Comment: Im seeing them downlaoding, it is definetly working. really appreciate the effort

Comment: Download is complete, But where will i now find the files?

Comment: Okay so i found the files on Jupyter and when i download and open them they work, is there a way to export them to my desktop? I tried to select all and download, but it only does 10 files at a time for some reason

Comment: Okay so i got the files to transfer to destkop will let u know if all is good but thanks for all your help anyway, you the GOAT

Comment: No prob, if everything's good please consider to mark the answer as the correct one, thanks!

Comment: @Federicofkt , please don't recommend outdated practices that may cause issues. Specifically, you should be recommending `%pip install` these days. In 2019, the magic install commands were added to insure that installation occurs in the proper environment where the kernel backing the active Jupyter `.ipynb` is running. The exclamation point along doesn't insure that and so the magic versions were added. They are current best practice and work universally in the modern Jupyter ecosystem now that they work in JupyterLite and Google Colab.  See more about the ...

Comment: <continued> modern `%pip install` command [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). [The second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.

Comment: @Wayne thanks, I was not aware of that, I've edited the post