# !pip opencv-python taking forerver

Tags: python, opencv, pip, computer-vision, facial-identification

I am working on a computer vision project and I'll need to install the cv2 into my python environment. However, while installing the `!pip install opencv-python`, I kept getting stuck here:

```
>jupyter) (1.2.3
Downloading install-1.3.5-py3-none-any.whl (3.2 kB)
Downloading webcolors-1.13-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Downloading fqdn-1.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.1 kB)
Downloading isoduration-20.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Downloading uri_template-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: opencv-python
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml) ..
```

[image]I am working on a computer vision project and need to install the cv2 into my python environment. However, when installing `!pip install opencv-python`, I encountered a persistent issue.

I tried using Gemini to solve the problem, and I was advised to follow these steps

Troubleshooting Steps:

**Monitor Progress:**
Let it continue for a reasonable time (larger packages can take upwards of 30 minutes).
Look for informative messages or errors in the installation log.

**Reinstall (if necessary):**
After troubleshooting, attempt a fresh installation.
Use `pip install --no-cache-dir opencv-python` to avoid cached files.
Consider a specific wheel file if available.

I have waited for more than 30 minutes and have also attempted the `pip install --no-cache-dir opencv-python` command, but I have yet to receive any positive feedback.

I keep getting stuck at `Building wheel for opencv-python...`

Comment: This won't help with the time of building the wheel; however, you are using outdated approaches of exclamation point with `pip`. I think. It is a but confusing because your post and screenshot don't actually show where you are running that line or what you are actually running. You shouldn't need an exclamation point on the command line in front of `pip`. And in my comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78159517/how-to-download-thousands-of-excel-files-from-website/78159636#comment137796367_78159636) I describe why you should be using `%pip install` in IPython and Jupyter.

Comment: <continued>  See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), pay special attention to the section 'Help others reproduce the problem'.  It talks about not sharing screenshots there. The code and output and a clear description of specific steps and where you are running would more valuable than what you provide.

Comment: Thanks Wayne. It finanlly worked after 3+ hours. Currently working with Computer Vision.

Comment: It looks like you're using Anaconda. Don't use `pip` with Anaconda, unless Anaconda doesn't provide the package. You can `conda install` OpenCV following the instructions here: https://github.com/conda-forge/opencv-feedstock

Comment: Thanks Cris, I'll try this next time. %pip.. worked